# R: Splitting comma-separated values from one column into a new dataframe (or how to use strsplit results)

Tags: r

I have a list of test results from two different groups that I've brought into R, and I have very little experience with R.  My current dataframe looks like this:

```
Samples <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
Test1 <- c("1","","300","NA","100, 2")
Test2 <- c("2","5000","3, 4000, 5","3","")
df <- data.frame(Samples, Test1, Test2)
```

And I'd like to (1) Break the cells with multiple, comma-separated values into different columns, (2) Fix the units of the tests so they match up - Test1 in this is sometimes reported on a scale which is off by a factor of 100 while Test2 reports are off by a factor of 1000, and (3) average the resulting values back into one column.

I started off like this:

```
#Replace blank cells with NA
df[df==""] <- "NA"
#Split cells with commas in them
split2 <- strsplit(df$Test2, split = "\\,")
```

And promptly got stuck.  How do I get the list created back into some sort of dataframe?  I don't know how many comma separated strings are in my giant dataset's column.  Most rows only have one result, but I know there are several with two and at least one with somewhere around eight. My two attempts to build a new dataframe (below) did not go well.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split2))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
data.frame(t(sapply(split2,c)))
  X1   X2           X3 X4 X5
1  2 5000 3,  4000,  5  3
```

I'm sure there's some way to do what I'm looking to do while still using the list and almost certainly some way to do this with a function/for loop.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Eventually, I'd like the data to look like this:

```
    Samples Test1 Test2
1       A     1     2
2       B    NA     5
3       C     3     4
4       D    NA     3
5       E   1.5    NA
```

Comment: How do you get the expected output from your input? Where does the 4 in Test2 come from? Where does the 3 and 1.5 in Test1 come from?

Comment: @aichao vmuir is expecting a conditional transformation to a common unit base i.e division by 100 for column 2 and division by 1000 but only for items that meet some unspecified condition of being greater than .... well , he does not actually say. I think there are many problems he doesn't realize, such as the fact that these columns are of factor-class on which `strsplit` will throw an error. I think it would be better to go back to the beginning where the data input errors were done and redo the data input.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following in this case: I create the data and calculate `split2` like you do (except I used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the data.frame.) and go on like this:

```
# get the maximal length of the vectors in split2
ncol_new <- max(sapply(split2, length))
# set the length of all of those elements to the maximal lenght
# this also fills them with NA values
split3 <- lapply(split2, `length<-`, ncol_new)
# transform the list of vectors to a matrix
new_cols <- matrix(unlist(split3), byrow=TRUE, ncol=ncol_new)
# set new colnames
colnames(new_cols) <- paste0("newCol", 1:ncol_new)
# and add the matrix to the dataframe as new columns
df <- cbind(df, new_cols)
```